# AMD-V not enabling in bios with Ubuntu 14.04 - Vagrant Up fails

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

If you are like me you have been running around in circles trying to fix this. I cannot enable AMD-V even though it says enabled in the BIOS.  I am simply trying to utilize puphpet to do a `vagrant up`

Here is my hardware/software

- Lenovo Edge E545 (AMD)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Vagrant 1.6.3
- VirtualBox 4.3.12 (4.2.24 attempted as fail-safe)
- BIOS version 1.09 (1.12 out but only has minor upgrades - nothing with AMD-V)

**Here is what I tried**

1. Clean install of Ubuntu 14.04
2. Installed VirtualBox and tried running `vagrant up` with multiple versions
3. Tried turning the BIOS setting for AMD-V on and off
4. Tried turning virtualization off and on in Virtual Box settings
5. Set processor to 2 and 1 in VirtualBox settings
6. Downloaded and installed 32bit virtualbox to 'try'.

**resolution?**: So I contacted Lenovo and AMD but both are pointing it towards being a software issue.  The Lenovo rep. recommended I return the laptop and get something Intel based.  Strange, but that is how I am "fixing" it.

**FIX**: Setting the 'virtualization' option to 'Disabled' in the BIOS fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

VT-x or AMD-V is required to run hardware accelerated virtualization, in this case lovely VirtualBox.

Run to see if your CPU is capable of AMD-V.

`egrep -wo '(vmx|svw)' /proc/cpuinfo`

You should expect a couple of (# of cores) `svw` in output.

When trying to bring up the VM using `vagrant up`, try to enable debug output by using `vagrant up --debug` to see more information. Update your question with more information.

Comment: Hmmm... not seeing vmx or svw.  I see `osvw`.  Also the processor is an AMD A6-5350M APU.  Am I better off with a different laptop or can I still develop with 32bit VMs? I thought most were 64bit.

Comment: @CGSmith105 This CPU is definitely 64-bit capable, but I am not 100% sure if it has AMD-V. AMD webiste doesn't provide a full spec of the CPU/APU like Intel does...

Comment: Make sure you enable AMD-V or any other virtualization related features in BIO

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this machine in a while but wanted to post back on what I found.

I continued to search around for answers and found nothing.  So I decided to go into the BIOS and change options until I found it to work.

I set Virtualization in the BIOS to 'Disabled' and can now boot to VMBox 64bit machines without error.

I hope this helps another soul.